# Tensor product surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, tensor-products, curves, bezier-curve

I'm studying Bézier surfaces and they are a special case of a more general construction, tensor product surfaces. I'd really like to know why this name. I am familiar only with the abstract (algebraic) definition of tensor product between two vector spaces using the universal property.

For reference a Bézier surface is a function $S(u,v)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}B_{i,n}(u)B_{j,m}(v)\mathbf{P}_{i,j}$ where $\mathbf{P}_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and  $B_{h,k}(x)$ is the $h$-th Bernstein basis polynomial of degree $k$.

Comment: The wikipedia page for "tensor product" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) might be helpful.

Comment: I didn't see anything that could help me because the only thing that comes near to what i need is the tensor product of linear maps